# Numpy: найти центр диагонали прямоугольника в двумерном массиве

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть двумерный массив, в котором есть -1(белый цвет), 128(серый) и 0(черный), найти центр прямоугольника(серым цветом) и заменить его на серый цвет, думаю, что можно взять координату на половине диагонали, как это сделать?

Вот у меня есть картинка моего массива.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот где-то так я хочу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. создаем изображение, в котором серые  рамки станут 0, остальное: 255. Типа im2=np.uint8(im1!=127). 
2. Используем функцию cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats которая выдаст центроиды x,y  внутренних частей серых прямоугольников. (нулевой элемент - фон, его не использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно - использовать данные о прямоугольнике, ведь он же был как-то нарисован - значит, и координаты имелись.

В этом случае

```
CenterX = (LeftTopX + RightBottomX) / 2
CenterY = (LeftTopY + RightBottomY) / 2
```

---

Если же это всё забыто, то надо искать самую верхнюю левую серую точку, и выполнять обход по серым точкам, опрашивая в первый раз направление вниз, потом против часовой стрелки. Т.е. в первую очередь проверяем направление влево от текущего направления, потом прямо. При повороте засекаем угол, далее используем его координаты.

При наличии нескольких контуров остальные обходим так же (при обходе первого можно запоминать, что точку серую нашли, но пока не задействовали)

Comment: Да, у меня есть координаты каждого прямоугольника, левого верхнего и правого нижнего углов, но как его написать, чтоб по центру была точка?

Comment: Просто среднее между ними - я формулу в ответ дописал